Hot to make nonwoven fabric material in Cycles?

Due to complexity I am unable to make this material with shader nodes. Can anybody please advice how to approach this?

I hope you don't mind my edit. If you ask for resources, this will just get closed as off-topic, but someone can help you learn instead. If you find that I changed the meaning of what you wanted to communicate, please edit the question again. It would be helpful if you describe what you have tried as far. What failed?

You could use a Voronoi texture as Bump map, put its Randomness at 0 and rotate it 45°, mix it with a Noise to have some nuance, also plug a Noise into the Base Color of the Principled BSDF to have a grainy color:

File: 

plz share file.

@atek, sure check my answer
